# How do teachers get grades in scorm package based test?

Tags: moodle, scorm

Is it manual or they get that automatically? What happens if there are more than 1 set of assignment for each subject?

Comment: Is this question about programming?  I seems off topic to me.

Answer (score -1):

The SCORM package will generate one or more scores *NOT* grades, they are merely measures on a scale. It is up to the "LMS", presumably in your case Moodle, to interpret a score on a course, section, objective, interaction, etc. into a "grade". What can be scored is dependent on the version of SCORM.

For Moodle this is most often done using a "Gradebook" plugin. How that plugin is configured is going to determine what types of grades are available, what scores are necessary to achieve a particular grade, how that grade is displayed, etc. See https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Grades